# How to add the values in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want my program to iterate through a column in google sheets, if the value is Null, then add the current value from an array to a variable(k). If the value is not Null then give me the total of the variable and make the variable zero again. This is the code I've written:

```js
for (let i = 2; i < 15; i++) {
  var k = 0;
  if (myStoreRange[i] == "") {
    k += myMarkRange[i];
    Logger.log(k);
  } else {
    Logger.log(k)
    mysheet.getRange("H3").setValue(k);
    k = myMarkRange[i];
    k = 0;
  }
}
```

However, when I run the code, the program is simply appending 0 to the value of the array, instead of adding the values. So, assuming first three number of array are [3, 5, 9] I'm getting 03, 05, 09 instead of 3, 8 17 etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few problems in your code:

- The null check. You stated that you want to check for null values (that would be `myStoreRange[i] === null`), but you are checking for empty strings (`myStoreRange[i] == ""`), make sure that is what you really want.
- `k += myMarkRange[i];` probably gives you this error of getting numbers 03, 05, etc. Check that myMarkRange is actually a list of numbers and not strings like "3","5". If the list has strings, when adding `k`(value 0) to `myMarkRange[i]`(value "3" of type string) you will be getting a string like "03". The solution for that is to cast the array to number: `k += Number(myMarkRange[i])`.
- I don't understand the last two lines. If you just want to reset the k variable to zero, the line before: `k = myMarkRange[i];` is not going to work. If you want to store the current `k` value in the current list element, that would be `myMarkRange[i] = k;`
- You are redeclaring the variable `k` to zero at the beginning of each iteration. This will cause it to always be zero, no matter if you stored a number in it in a previous iteration. I'd suggest moving it outside the loop:

```js
var k = 0;
for (let i = 2; i < 15; i++) {
```

- This last tip won't solve your problem, but it's considered a good practice to avoid using `var` declarations and, instead, use `let` in this case (`let k = 0;`), so the variable is defined in the scope of wherever you execute this code, and not globally.

Comment: Hi Victor, I just wanted to thank you for your clear and well thought out response. You solved our problem! Firstly I was declaring the k value to zero inside the iteration, but also, using the Number(myMarkRange[i]) solved the problem. I'm not sure why sheets was converting the numbers to text -they were definitely entered as numbers but stating it in the program solved the problem.